# css media query applying to full size page

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm using media queries on my page for smaller screens but it's applying when the page is in full size. when the page is in full size I have the `h1` at `5rem` but it shows in `2.5rem`. Thank you in advance.

```
@media (min-width: 375px) {
  .container {
      padding: 0 2rem 0 2rem;
  }
  .container h1 {
      font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: use `max-width` instead of `min-width`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

specify `screen` to your css media query and also use `max-width` and not `min-width`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .container {
      padding: 0 2rem 0 2rem;
  }
  .container h1 {
      font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@media (max-width: 375px) {
  .container {
      padding: 0 2rem 0 2rem;
  }
  .container h1 {
      font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
}
```

**min-width** for bigger screen. For smaller screen use **max-width**